# Replacing two instructions with one instruction in assembly language

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, instructions

[image]

Here is a table of a number of instructions given in a program. The first column indicates the instruction itself, the second column indicates the percent of weightage of any instruction in a program, and the third column indicates the CPI(cycles per instruction) of any given instruction.

Now, I want to replace the **add** and **mult** with one instruction **madd**.

> **madd** takes three inputs, multiplies the first two inputs and add the result to the third input. This way **madd** instruction does both the multiplication and addition.

Current weight of both **add** and **mult** is 40%. So the question is when I replace the **mult** and **add** with **madd** what will be the weight of new **madd** instruction?

Comment: What do you think it will be? What have you done so far to solve it?

Comment: Is that a homework?

Comment: @user28434 it is a sub part of one problem. And I'm stuck here.

Comment: @Colin__s I have combined 10% of **add**  with 10% of **mult**. That will leave 20% of **add** with us. So, in result , we will have 10% of **madd** instructions and will be left with 20% of **add** instructions.
So in general, We had 40% of instructions for **add** and **mult** combined before. Now, we have 10% of **madd** plus 20% of **add** instructions.

Comment: You need to make an assumption here: That is 10% of ADD instructions will use the output of MULT as one source. Given that assumption, the direction you are heading is correct. Also remember to modify the CPI in the newly formed MADD instruction.

Comment: @ParthS. but that would change the total percentages of everything, consider: 5x load, 5x store, 6x add, 2x mult, 2x branch = 20 total in old version -> 5x load, 5x store, 4x add, 2x madd, 2x branch = 18 total, so load is now 27.78%, not 25%, etc... (I automatically found the smallest representation, but instead I could have used the percentages directly as amount of instructions, like 25x store, 30x add, 10x mult ... then old version has 100 in total, new version only 90 -> 25/90 = 27.78% of stores, etc... this way its probably easier to comprehend for others)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Current weight of both add and mult is 40%. So the question is when I
>   replace the mult and add with madd what will be the weight of new madd
>   instruction?

If the program consists of additions (that consume 30% of CPU time) in one place, and multiplications (that consume 10% of CPU time) in a completely different place that has nothing to do with the additions; then it may be completely impossible to replace anything with a "multiply and add" instruction.

If the program consists of one addition (that consume 30% of CPU time by itself) and 1000 multiplications (that consume 0.01% of CPU time each) then for "best case" you can only replace one addition and one multiplication and you'd still have 999 "unpaired" multiplications.

If the program consists of 1000 additions (that consume 0.03% of CPU time each) and one multiplication (that consumes 10% of CPU time by itself) then for "best case" you can only replace one addition and one multiplication and you'd still have 999 "unpaired" additions.

If you know that there are an equal number of additions and multiplications and all of them can be paired and replaced by "multiply and add" instructions **without changing the number of loads, stores or branches**; then you have no idea how fast/slow a "multiply and add" instruction is (or at least you haven't provided that information) and therefore it would still impossible to figure out how it would effect performance.

In other words, you've got almost none of the information that would be needed to find an answer.

Comment: If the architecture has a zero register, then all multiplies can be replaced by madd. If  it has a one register, then additions can also be encoded as madd (Itanium did have a 1.0 register as well as a 0.0 register for this purpose). If these operations are entirely independent, 40% of instructions would be madd. If every multiply in the program is followed by a dependent add (best case), then a third of instructions would be madd (20 independent adds and  10 true madds for every 90 instructions [100 - 10 subsumed adds]). Performance is not part of the question.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton: Performance (the percentage of CPU time spent executing which types of instructions) is the question, it's just that the OP calls it "weight".

Comment: I think by "weight" the OP means % of *instruction count*, which fits with "Current weight of both add and mult is 40%" (the performance fraction of mult and add is 2.2/5.9, 37%).